# What does the output from `print(some_object)` mean?

Tags: python, class, object, variables, output

what is the meaning of this output from a Python code:

```
<class 'mediapipe.python.solution_base.SolutionOutputs'>
```

does it mean that we are printing an object of a 'mediapipe.python.solution_base.SolutionOutputs' class? I mean for example, if I declare a class like:

```
class Apple():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 45

    def temp(self):
        pass
```

and then I make an object of this class,

```
a = Apple()
```

and then if I print a, like

```
print(a)
```

should I get,

```
<class 'Apple'>
```

Comment: With your class definition, try `print(Apple())` and `print(Apple)`. Do you see the difference between printing an __instance of the class__, vs __the class itself__?

Comment: If you're seeing this output when you expected to see an instance, it generally means you forgot to write `()` when creating the instance.

Comment: That looks like the default representation of a  **class** not an *instance of the class*

Comment: "should I get" **do you get**? What happens when you run the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain by example. Here's the code:

```
class Apple():
    ...

class Banana:
    def __str__(self):
        return 'I am a banana'

print(Apple()) # p1
print(Apple) # p2

print(Banana()) # p3
print(Banana) # p4
```

...and here's the output:

```
<__main__.Apple object at 0x10afa4950>
<class '__main__.Apple'>
I am a banana
<class '__main__.Banana'>
```

If we run this script (let's call it foo.py) as *python foo.py* then our module (the value assigned to __name__) will be __main__

At p1 we have instantiated an instance of Apple. *print()* will try to find an implementation of the __str__ dunder method. If it exists, it will execute it and emit the returned value. If __str__ isn't available it will look for __repr__ and behave similarly. If neither are available it will show the module name, the name of the class and its id. That's what we see in the first output line.

At p2 we are printing the class - not an instance of that class. Therefore there are no dunder methods to be called and we simply see that it is a class called Apple in the __main__ module.

At p3 we are printing an instance of the Banana class which implements __str__ hence the output 'I am a banana' as explained previously.

At p4 yet again we are just printing the class and although it has __str__ implemented that's irrelevant as it's not an instance of that class

Answer (score 0):

Using your `Apple` example:

```py
class Apple:
    pass

a = Apple()

print(a)  # printing an instance of a class by using `a.__str__()`
#=> <__main__.Apple object at 0x11b02b6d0>

print(Apple)  # printing the class itself
#=> <class '__main__.Apple'>
```

`a.__str__()` by default returns a string with the class, that it's an object, and the memory address where it's stored.